# Custom action bar theme not working for newer devices

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-theme

I followed [this tutorial](http://www.androiduipatterns.com/2012/09/creating-custom-android-styles-easy-way.html) exactly in order to apply a custom theme to my app - using both the Action Bar Style Generator and the Holo Colors Generator. This app targets API 10+. When I run the app on an API 10 device (Nexus One 2.3.7 in Genymotion Simulator), it works very well and the custom theme is fully visible. But when I run the app on an API 18 device (HTC One 4.3 in Genymotion Simulator), the custom action bar styles are not applied, as if I didn't change the app's theme. However, the components (like the Text Select Handles generated via Holo Colors Generator) are visible. That's also the case for 4.4.4 devices. Why is that, how can I apply this theme to all APIs 10+?

If it's relevant, this is how I create the action bar and tabs:

```
ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();

String[] sections = //make array of tab titles

for (int i = 0; i < sections.length; i++) {
    ActionBar.Tab tab = bar.newTab();
    tab.setText(sections[i]);
    tab.setTabListener(new TabListener(i));
    bar.addTab(tab, false);
}

bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
```

Comment: When you use the [Android-holo-colors](http://android-holo-colors.com/), did you set the Min SDK version >= 11? If you did, the custom styles should only apply on SDK 11 or higher. If you did not, the custom styles will only apply on SDK 10 or lower, so SDK 18 wont work.

Comment: @ztan Actually the components generated by Holo Colors do show up on all devices, it's only the Action Bar styles that don't show up on newer devices.

Comment: Android-holo-colors doesnt work for all devices. You have to choose either <11 or >=11. So if you want to support new devices, choose >= in Android-holo-colors, generate a new zip and set the min SDK version to 11 in your project.

Comment: @ztan Changing it to >=11 and merging replacing the files didn't solve the problem - still shows the default action bar theme. That generator wasn't the problem, it's the action bar styles that don't appear on new devices not the android holo colors resources.